# Disable Cancel button before POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking `Submit` button my **JavaScript** code execute  `$.post("Submit.aspx",...` that sometimes takes a few seconds so user  is able to click `Back` button that is undesirable.

**So I try to disable or hide Back button but it does not work and it is still clickable.** Any clue?

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="next" onclick="submitData()" />
<input type="submit" id="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="goBack()" />

function submitData()
{
   // I try to disable or hide Back button but it does not work 
  $('#btnBack').hide();
  $('#btnBack').attr("disabled",true);
  var btnBack= document.getElementById("btnBack").disabled = true;


   // Long request
   $.post("Submit.aspx",..
}
```

Comment: `console.log($('#btnBack'));` ? r u sure that '#btnBack' finds element?

Comment: do you have errors on the developer console .hide should definitely work if jquery is there

Comment: @AlexandrX Yes it finds the element. But does not hide or disable the element.

Comment: @Dimi , try in console: `$('#btnBack').hide();`, what is the effect?

Comment: @AlexandrX Well it returns the found element but does no hide it.

Comment: @Dimi what exactly u r see in console? copypaste pls

Comment: @AlexandrX It works if I use the class but not the id the id is the same and correct.

Comment: hmmm... could it be that there are two elements with the same ID on your page?   and I repeat - lets see to your console exact output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be right. Did you add Jquery?

Check the this:

```js
function submitData(){
   // I try to disable or hide Back button but it does not work 
  $('#btnBack').hide();
  $('#btnBack').attr("disabled",true);
  var btnBack= document.getElementById("btnBack").disabled = true;

}

function goBack(){
  console.log("I'm back");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="next" onclick="submitData()" />
<input type="submit" id="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="goBack()" />
```

Comment: What I can say that in your example code works find but in mine does not.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`$(el).prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for disabling the input. Also when you are using jQuery, you don't need to add `onclick` in html, you can do it like Eg below:

```js
$('input[value="Submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#btnBack').prop("disabled",true);
   //your post request
   //$.post("Submit.aspx",..
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="next" />
<input type="submit" id="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="goBack()" />
```

For your code it will be:

```
function submitData() {
    $('#btnBack').prop("disabled",true);
    $.post("Submit.aspx",..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
canSubmit = true;
function submitData(){
    if(!canSubmit){
         return false;
    }
    canSubmit = false;

    // disabling button
    $('#btnBack').attr("disabled", true);

     // Long request
     $.post("Submit.aspx", ...).always(function(){ canSubmit = true; });
}
```

Simply use a variable and check for this value before submitting form and after ajax request response reset it value. BTW you can disable button if you want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnBack").prop('disabled', true);
```

Instead of

```
$('#btnBack').attr("disabled",true);
```

Comment: not sure that is a problem. `$('#btnBack').hide();` should hide it anyway

Comment: My code doesn't hide it, it disables it. Give it a go and remove the other bits where you are using `.hide()` and `var btnBack= document.getElementById("btnBack").disabled = true;`

Comment: in asker's code he tries to **hide** element, and it doesnt work too

Comment: 'I try to disable **or** hide'

Answer (score 0):

I had two button with the same name and that confuses jQuery it cannot execute the hide() method when it was invoked. in the course of researching to know what was happening, I came across this post with the comments of  AlexandrX which gave a clue to what may be causing the problem. I removed the duplicate cancelButton and everything works well.
This is of great help.

Thank you so much.